# Firebase check Date in ISO format

Tags: firebase

I am saving my date in an ISO-format (e.g. "2017-09-29T15:17:00.000Z"). Is there a way within firebase rules to validate if the given date is prior to the current date. Also, is it bad practice to do it that way (I want to identify the date on the first glimpse inside my database)?

I currently have the following:

```
".validate": "newData.val() > now"
```

But apparently, this doesn't work if the given value is not in the typical date-format. What I need is something like

```
new Date(newData.val()) > now) // I want something like this
```

Comment: I think that you need to use Cloud Functions for advanced functionality like that.

Comment: You'll need to store the date in milliseconds since epoch, which is the format of `now`.